# Why does my filter don't work when I use select2 class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2

I'm Trying to solve a bug where my select bugs because of select2 class.

Here are some pics that shows whats happening:

[image: In left how its working, in right how it has to work]
Note that the options shown are totally different.

here is the parts of my code that might be useful:

This is the HTML of my element:

```
<div class="col">
  <h4>Território a ser retirado</h4>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row">
     <select class="select2">
        <option value="0">Selecione um território</option>
     </select>
     <button id="RetirarExecutivoTerritorio" class="btn color-btn-femsa btn-rounded btn-danger"
          title="Retirar"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fw"></i>
          @* Retirar *@
     </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this part I do my options:

```
response.Territorios.forEach((elem) => {
  if (elem.CmpExecutivoResponsavel != null) {
    territoriosComExecutivo += `<option idExecutivo="${elem.CmpExecutivoResponsavel}" value="${elem.CmpCoTerritorio}">${elem.CmpNoTerritorio}</option>`;
  } else {
    territoriosSemExecutivo += `<option value="${elem.CmpCoTerritorio}">${elem.CmpNoTerritorio}</option>`;
  }
});
```

Here i fill my select with these options:

```
('#TerritorioRetirar').append(territoriosComExecutivo);
```

And finally here where i make this filter:

```
async HandleExcutivoTerritorioSelecionado() {
$('#EmailExecutivoTerritorioRetirar').change(() => {
  let id_executivo = $('#EmailExecutivoTerritorioRetirar').val();

  // coloca sempre na opção neutra selecionada
  $('#TerritorioRetirar').val('0').change();

  if (id_executivo == '0') {
    $('#TerritorioRetirar').val('0').change();
  } else {
    // percorre todos os options do select, para filtrar apenas os territórios responsáveis
    // para aquele executivo selecionado.
    $('#TerritorioRetirar > option').each(function () {
      let id_territorio = $(this).attr('idExecutivo');

      if (id_territorio == id_executivo) {
        $(this).show();
      } else if (id_territorio != id_executivo && id_territorio != undefined) {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

}

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Please can you show your code in a text format instead of pics, it would really help us discover the problem quickly.

Comment: Hello. Create a snippet reproducing your problem and I'll take a look :)